# why can’t I get the text of this webelement through the xpath

Tags: html, xpath

Why can't I get the text of this webelement?

```
String text  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/span[1]")).getText();
System.out.println(text);
```

This is the HTML:

```
<span class="pane-legend-item-value-wrap">
<span class="pane-legend-item-value pane-legend-line" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255);">58647.3451</span></span>
```

Comment: Why the css tag and not the xpath tag?

Comment: it was an error

Comment: share the little more DOM structure of the element there are some unique identifiers needed to fetch the single element